# Accessing a shared office365 mailbox via powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I have shared mailbox on office365 which doesnt have a user account associated with it i.e. I cant login to it via the office 365 portal.  I access to it via Outlook as a shared mailbox hence my account has permission to view the inbox.

I have used the powershell script found [here](https://sysadminben.wordpress.com/2015/10/27/reading-emails-from-office365-account-using-powershell/) and I have barely amended it except to change the `$mail` and `$password`.

If I use my own account credentials I can loop through the foreach loop and observe it accessing my emails which is great.  I want to however access a shared mailbox called shared@mailbox.com instead of myAccount@mailbox.com.

To attempt to do this I added a username variable and passed this to `$service.credentials` and passed the $mail variable to `$service.autodiscover`.  See code below.

This did not work....

Can anyone help?

```
$username="myAccount@mailbox.com"
$password="myPassword"
$mail = "shared@mailbox.com"

# Set the path to your copy of EWS Managed API 
$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll" 
# Load the Assemply 
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath) 

# Create a new Exchange service object 
$service = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService 

#These are your O365 credentials
$Service.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials($username,$password)

# this TestUrlCallback is purely a security check
$TestUrlCallback = {
    param ([string] $url)
    if ($url -eq "https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml") {$true} else {$false}
}

# Autodiscover using the mail address set above
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($mail,$TestUrlCallback)
```